# cannot close dialog with iframe that contents a pdf

Tags: jquery, iframe

Im using jquery ui, dialog in particular, I am opening a modal window that contains an iframe, the iframe contains a pdf url, when i try to close the modal window in internet explorer 10 and 9, i cant, the viwer that contains the pdf file its impossible to close... any idea?

```
$("#x").append($("<div><iframe width='1000' height='600' scrolling='yes' align='top'>    </iframe></div>").attr("src", "x.pdf")).dialog({width:1010, height: 610, modal: true, title: 'Hello', closeOnEscape: true });

<a id="x">LINK</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Chrome browser?

Comment: Hi Yoann with Chrome works perfectly, thanks a lot.